# How can a Windows system be backed up so that files on the backup medium are still readable without the backup software?

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup

I use macOS and Linux almost exclusively. On those systems, it is possible, using various software, to create backups where the individual files on the backup medium are human-readable, i.e. the folder structure is retained and files keep their names. This has the advantage that file can be manually restored even if the backup software should be unavailable (e.g. when retrieving something from a 6 year old backup disk that was created with an older OS version). Conversely, there are many backup tools that create proprietary data structures on the target medium that allow all sorts of nice recovery scenarios -- but all require the restore to be done using the original software.

I need to set up a backup system for household scenarios with just this "human-readable" property.

What is "the Windows way" of achieving this? Is it just a matter of choosing a certain backup tool (Windows' file versioning, for example, does not describe anything comparable in its documentation) or are special procedures necessary, and is this even possible given Windows' special files and data structures like the registry?

Comment: W10 has what is called file history that backs up files, then you can browse file history to view what is backed up>>>>https://lifehacker.com/how-to-back-up-your-computer-automatically-with-windows-1762867473

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly called it "file versioning" in my question. Well, as stated above, its technical documentation does not describe anything related to my requirements...